# no gnome-do package for ubuntu(studio) 20.04 LTS. Options?

Tags: apt, gnome-do

I [see](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+source/gnome-do) there is no gnome-do package for ubuntu 20.04 any longer.
Has it been repackaged in another package perhaps?
Is there some replacement tool ? I am mostly interested in its folder indexing-and-open where you could start typing folder names to open them. This is a feature that xfce4-whiskermenu is missing.

Google returns no options for adding it through a ppa or otherwise. Is there some way to revive this package? A replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for alternatives and it looks like `synapse` package not only covers my use case but and offers a similar UI to that of `gnome-do`

Answer (score 2):

If you really need this application, then you can grab its packages from 18.04 LTS repository directly:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libg/libgnome-keyring/libgnome-keyring-common_3.12.0-1build1_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libg/libgnome-keyring/libgnome-keyring0_3.12.0-1build1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-sharp2/libgconf2.0-cil_2.24.2-4_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-desktop3/libgnome-desktop-3-17_3.28.2-0ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-keyring-sharp/libgnome-keyring1.0-cil_1.0.0-5_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-do/gnome-do_0.95.3-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./gnome-do_0.95.3-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./libgconf2.0-cil_2.24.2-4_all.deb ./libgnome-desktop-3-17_3.28.2-0ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb ./libgnome-keyring1.0-cil_1.0.0-5_amd64.deb ./libgnome-keyring0_3.12.0-1build1_amd64.deb ./multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb ./libgnome-keyring-common_3.12.0-1build1_all.deb
```

and then use GNOME Do.

Answer (score 0):

I remember synapse being there along with gnome-do and recently had to search for alternative since Ubuntu 20.04. I found ULauncher and it served the function as well. I just nuked and restored my system, checked to see what's up with gnome-do and found this post. Glad I did. I like synapse's UI a bit better. Let's hope it doesn't meet same fate as gnome-do (fingers crossed).